# Unsure whether to stay on a job that I started just a week ago

Tags: job-offer, new-job, work-life-balance

I am an expat working as Software Engineer in one of the Asian countries. After working for a year on my second job, I decided to move to another company as I was not learning anything in that job at all neither the job had any challenged for me.

Through connections and of curse an interview, I got an offer from a large company to work as a **Senior Software Engineer**. The job was also offering my 50 percent of increment on my Salary which sounded reasonable to me. Considering the higher role and higher salary, I resign and accepted the new offer.

**Only after accepting the offer**, I begin to realized what kind of company am I going to enter. the manger started dragging me into their projects and assigning some tasks to me before starting my job, and his justification was that he wants be to be familiar with their project. (He just needed manpower)

Long story short, I have already started the job, and on my first day of work, I worked for 13 hours. I feel I am being a slave in this company and I am not sure if I should consider looking for jobs or staying where I am for now.

Here are the things this company offering me :

- Above average Salary for my years of experience.
- Above average job title for my years of experience.
- Challenging and complex project which I can learn a lot from.

**Here is the thing this company taking a way from me :**

- My life. ( I wake up in the morning, and go to office, by the time I get home is already later night. even if I manged to get home early, I would need to attend calls and meetings and continue the work)

**What would be your advice to me in this situation? To stay for a while and grow in the technical area, or give up and move else where?**

Comment: This isn't something we can answer as it stands, and it will likely be closed - it's a choice that only you can make really. That said, in my own personal experience I've been-there-done-that with jobs that obilterate your life and it's just not worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Check the [tour] and [help/on-topic] to see if you can reword your question to be more practical and answerable. As @motosubatsu said "what should I do?" doesn't fit our format. A question similar to the one asked [in this external blog post](http://www.askamanager.org/2013/05/how-soon-can-you-tell-if-a-job-isnt-right-for-you.html) would be more appropriate here. Regardless I'd encourage you to give that article a read in the meanwhile.

Comment: I am offering my advice here since the question is put on hold. What you described is a typical working environment in Asian countries.(check my user profile, please). This is why and how the economy in this region is booming. If you don't like this, leave the region as soon as possible because I am afraid the next good job you can find in there is similar. BTW, if you can survive a year, you may be able to get a big bonus. Check with your co-worker/manager.

Comment: Further on bonus. In my opinion, Work 13 hrs a day is not worth 50% salary increase. However, many companies in Asia offer year end bonus. Depending on how well the company business is in the past year, the bonus can range from 2 months to even 20 months salary. In Taiwan, most companies give the bonus before Chinese new year. My next door neighbor used his bonus to buy a new car (Lexus) last week.

Comment: @scaaahu, I don't get such bonus. In fact, I don't get anything besides the salary.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know that. Please disregard my comment above.

Comment: @comxyz - Different customs and laws, along with what other employees will put up with, in different countries. In NA, compared to Asia -- Wages:  8 + (5 * 1.5) = 15.5 hours of work per day for 50% wage increase = lousy. - Fancy Title: costs company nothing, might help your resume. - More Challenging Work: That's what you asked for. --- You want almost 3x to work 2x on more difficult work; you negotiated strongly against yourself. If you can't be certain of **super** bonuses you'll be tired, broken and miserable. Long and hard work is a 'source of pride' in some places, elsewhere it's cash.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think a week is long enough to judge what the job will be like long term.  I would give it more time, at least 90 days.  If the long hours continue then it looks like your 50% increase in salary is not quite a 50% increase at all if your workload has gone up 40-50%.  Whatever you do, don’t adapt your lifestyle to your new pay “increase” by making big purchases or taking on debt.  If you do you’ll run the risk of being stuck there because you’ll need the additional money that the new job is providing.